# How to launch shell script from awk command

Tags: shell, awk

I am a novice in ksh scripting and would highly appreciate any help.
I need to parse data file that looks like this:

```
$ cat data.txt
P1`/tmp/s1.ksh
P2`/tmp/s2.ksh
P3`/tmp/s3.ksh
```

Here P1, P2, P3 are parameter names, followed by script names, which calculate the values for those parameters.

Dummy scripts look like this:

```
$ cat s1.ksh
!/bin/ksh
echo "v1"
```

At the end, I need to launch those scripts and concatenate their results with parameter names and produce a string that looks like this:

```
P1=v1 P2=v2 P3=v3
```

I try to use awk to do this. As I understood, system() should launch the scripts and print their output to the resulting string.

```
$ awk -F\` '{ printf("%s ",$1); system("eval \"$(cat "$2")\"") }' /tmp/data.txt
```

But it only prints parameter names

```
P1 P2 P3
```

I checked if I parsed the data.txt correctly

```
$ awk -F\` '{ printf(" %s=",$1); printf("eval \"$(cat %s)\"", $2) }' /tmp/data.txt
```

The output is

```
P1=eval "$(cat /tmp/s1.ksh)" P2=eval "$(cat /tmp/s2.ksh)" P3=eval "$(cat /tmp/s3.ksh)"
```

So, I expect that system() should execute the following command and concatenate its output with a resulting string.

```
$ eval "$(cat /tmp/s2.ksh)"
```

Could you please help me and explain why I did not get values v1, v2, v3 from the scripts. Maybe there is a better way than using awk to solve my task.

Comment: Actually I tried this and it worked on my Ubuntu 14.04. I got the expected output.
By the way, the shebang at the start of the scripts must start with #: `#!/bin/ksh`

Comment: This sounds like the XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Edit your question to show clear sample input and expected output and we can help you do it the right way, whatever it is.

Comment: Ed Morton, this sounds like you did not read my post. There was an input data, and expecting output.

Comment: Midihenry, thank you. #! was a tipo, sorry for that.Indeed, that code works in bash.But it did not work in SunOS 5.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$ nawk -F\` '{ printf("%s ",$1); system("eval "$2) }' /tmp/data.txt
```

It produces:

```
P1 v1
P2 v2
P3 v3
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
echo $(
while IFS=\\` read p sc
do
  $sc $p
done < data.txt )
```

the shell loop splits the lines in the file and runs each script with each param.
The echo $() is to run the loop and collect its output, and echo that, which has the effect of removing newlines.